# can i run useEffect with onClick?

Tags: reactjs

```
const test = () => {
   useEffect(() => {
      setState("test")
}, [testDependency])
}   
<button onClick={() => Test()}>btn</button>
```

hey guys, im trying to run this function, but i keep getting an error that says im breaking hook rules.

Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons

but i cant find which one, anyone knows??

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are violating rules of hooks.
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html Please take a look at this document.

In your case you are calling useEffect hook inside the simple function which is wrong approach.

What you can do is, Simply

```
const [testState, setTestState] = React.useState()
        
useEffect(() => {
    // do your stuff here when the state of testState is updated
 }, [testState])
    

const Test = () => {
    setTestState("test")
 }


<button onClick={() => Test()}>btn</button>
```

[image]